# How do I find out what webcam driver is in use?

Tags: drivers, webcam, troubleshooting

I need to troubleshoot a webcam that stopped working correctly in Ubuntu 12.04. It's always worked "out of the box" in the past so I have no idea what driver it uses.

How do I go about looking that up?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to see all the loaded driver modules in the system.

Open terminal then type

```
lsmod
```

And see if your driver is listed in the modules or not

there is also another command that list the PCI modules

```
lspci
```

Comment: 1) There are 106 kernel modules listed by `lsmod`. How do I know which one the webcam is using? 2) I don't see any modules listed by `lspci`. Can you please elaborate on what I'm supposed to do with this?